# Hide rows in a worksheet based on a cell value in different worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to Hide rows 24 to 26 of a worksheet called "RS" if the value of cell H37 of a worksheet called "calculation sheet" is below 15,000

I have tried to use/combine formulas within VBA as previsouly used personally & on this forum but it didn't work. I am not too sure about the if function.

Thanking you in advance for your help. 
Abs

Comment: i think this cant be achieved by formulas. You need to use code. When macro should be executed?

Comment: That's what I tried to do which is why it says using VBA in the title :)

Comment: Maybe next time try to insert what code you have and what is not working...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it if you don't need anything to happen if `H37` on the "calculated fields" sheet is >= 15,000

```
Sub test()

If Sheets("calculation sheet").Range("H37").Value < 15000 Then

Sheets("RS").Rows("24:26").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't need it to do anything if the value is over 15,000. The above formula does not seem to work for me .

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in the `Worksheet` module for the "Calculation Sheet".

This code will fire every time a calculation is made on the Calculation Sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Worksheets("RS").Rows("24:26").EntireRow.Hidden = Me.Range("H37").Value < 15000

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you. it does not work, I don't see where in your code you have the part which would go to worksheet called "RS" to hide rows 24:26? Doesn't the code you provided above remain in the same worksheet called "Calculation sheet". H37 is driven by a formula, you are correct.

Comment: @Abigal - see my edits. I overlooked the "RS" sheet.

Comment: it still doesn't work for me. Why is it called "worksheet_calculate()" It doesn't do anything even when I typed in a number in H37 instead of leaving the initial formula in.

Comment: @Abigal if you manually type a number you need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event. You can google Excel Worksheet Events to read more. I deleted the `Worksheet_Change` event code because you said it was formula driven (meaning only a calculate would induce a change). If you need the `Worksheet_Change` event let me know. Also, is the formula in `H37` linked to another sheet?

Comment: @Abigal - I am glad you it works for me. Please tick the green check mark to mark the question as answered so that others know it was a working solution, moving forward.